# Large Video file Conversion using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg tool to convert videos from wmv to mp4 formats using the following code -

```
        string outputPath = args[1].ToString();
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(inputPath);               
        Console.WriteLine(files.Length);
        foreach (var item in files)
        {
            itemBkp = item;                                       
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"e:\test\ffmpeg.exe";                   
            string filename= Path.GetFileName(item);                    
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments=  " -i "  + item + " " + outputPath + filename.Split('.')[0] + ".mp4";
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
        }
```

It works fine for videos up to 20mb but when i try for videos above 70mb it throws following error -

FFmpeg version SVN-r6179, Copyright (c) 2000-2004 Fabrice Bellard configuration: --extra-cflags=-I/static/include --extra-ldflags=-L/static/lib --enable-memalign-hack --enable-mp3lame --enable-xvid --enable-a52 --enable-libogg --enable-vorbis --enable-faac --enable-faad --enable-x264 --enable-pp --enable-amr_wb --enable-amr_nb --enable-avisynth --enable-gpl libavutil version: 49.0.0 libavcodec version: 51.13.0 libavformat version: 50.5.0 built on Sep 5 2006 22:41:30, gcc: 3.4.5 (mingw special) E:\videos\Playful: I/O error occured Usually that means that input file is truncated and/or corrupted.

Is there a limit on video size to be converted?

Comment: Cannot trace your problem without source. I tried to bind the libraries, built from source in MINGW-64 / g++. On source-level it seems like an example of failed encapsulation of memory management, systematically asking for segmentation faults. In my case performed as reset on the input stream several times and subsequent reading will crash. Found, that the sister project "libav" was stable. May be their avconv.exe is an option.

Comment: `FFmpeg version SVN-r6179, Copyright (c) 2000-2004` This might be the oldest ffmpeg I've seen on this site, and I've seen thousands of ffmpeg questions. It's even older than some of the people asking questions here. Please [upgrade](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/packages/) before doing anything else.

Comment: @SamGinrich Libav is dead, but I guess that can be considered "stable" since it will never change.

Comment: :) So we have older and newer versions of crash ware, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating ffmpeg to latest version solved my issue. Thankyou everyone for your comments.